# How does System.Data.OracleClient finds installed OracleClient

Tags: oracle, ado.net, oracleclient

I wonder how does library System.Data.OracleClient finds installed on machine OracleClient. I've reinstalled the client, but still get error "OracleClient requires Oracle client software", which seem rather suspicious, because client is installed on pc, it has entries in registry and path to oracle client in PATH variable.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the oracle client version required by System.Data.OracleClient is the same as the one you have?

Comment: I've checked it already, the version is even greater then minimum version required.

Comment: Still don't know what was the problem, but solved it in another way. As System.Data.OracleClient is obsolete I refactored code for using Oracle.Data.Client from Oracle Data Provider from ODP.NET 4.0, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

1. Add the environment variable ORACLE_HOME, with the value equal to the base of the install directory (e.g. C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1)
2. Make sure that %ORACLE_HOME%\bin\ is in the PATH (the setup program should have already put it in there)

Agreed that using ODP.NET is better than deprecated System.Data.OracleClient.

Comment: ODP is for sure better, because it install oracle client at the same time.

Comment: Well, avoiding System.Data.OracleClient is worth avoiding for more reasons than that. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx